# link to logged in profile asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm new to asp.net c#. 
i have a site with profiles, and when you log into the site a button appears that say " my profile" i want that to link to the logged in useres profile

This is all i could come up with :(

```
<li class="topmenu"><a href="profile.aspx?id=<%#Eval("user_id") %>">My Profile</a></li>
```

I have the profile.aspx site ready with all the Eval('s) and such, i just dont know how to link to the logged in profile.

further down the site i use the same link as above, and this piece of code to show 3 random profiles, with just their name picture and age from the database and a link to the profile and it works just fine, perhaps i can use some of that?

```
<a href="profile.aspx?id=<%#Eval("profile_id") %>">...Show profile</a>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:DatabaseConnectionString1 %>" SelectCommand="SELECT TOP 3 * FROM profiles ORDER BY NEWID()"></asp:SqlDataSource>
```

**Codebehind**

```
public int PorfileId
{
    get
    {

        int ProfileId = 0;
        if (int.TryParse(Request.QueryString["id"].ToString(), out ProfileId))
        {
            return ProfileId;
        }
        return ProfileId;
    }
```

And on the profile.aspx i use this..

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource_nyhed" runat="server" ConnectionString='<%$ ConnectionStrings:DatabaseConnectionString1 %>' SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [profiles] WHERE ([profile_id] = @profile_id)">
```

Comment: PorfileId? You may have made a syntax error

Comment: well most of the code i posted works. and i just renamed the " profile " from danish bruger so it worked before i posted it here atleast.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well i kinda figured it out i dont know if its a cheap way but this works for me now.

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource3">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <a href="profilNormal.aspx?id=<%#Eval("bruger_id") %>">Min profil</a>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>

<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource3" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:DatabaseConnectionString1 %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [bruger_id] FROM [brugere] WHERE ([bruger_id] = @bruger_id)">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:SessionParameter SessionField="login_id" Name="bruger_id" Type="Int32"></asp:SessionParameter>
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```